# How do I install NVIDIA drivers for very old GPU on antix 17?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, proprietary-drivers

I have a very very old PC that I found lying on the street. I'm actually typing this post from it, here are the specs:

- CPU: AMD Athlon XP 2500+ (32-bit) (decent CPU, lacks SSE2 instruction set making life hell)
- GPU: NVIDIA Riva TNT2 64
- RAM: 1GB DDR (don't know the speed)
- HDD: 40GB IDE Drive
- PSU: 200w (probably off-brand)

The lack of the SSE2 instruction set limits my possibilities a lot, so I decided to go with a true lightweight distro, antix 17. The machine works at a reasonable speed, better than I'd expect from these specs, but I'm having trouble installing the NVIDIA drivers. It's currently using the noveau drivers, and we all know how crappy those are. The OS comes with an app to install the drivers, but it crashes whenever I launch it, so I need to do a manual installation. I found [these](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/35626/en-us) drivers, but I never installed them this way. So I downloaded the file and chmodded it to try to run it, it told me I was running an x server. No big deal, I logged out and tried again from CLI, then it told me that the kernel header files didn't exist, and that was probably because I hadn't configured it. So I'm stuck here. Reading online it looks to be a compatibility problem with the kernel and the driver version, in which case I guess I'm kinda screwed. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

antix forum is usually quite responsive for Q&As. I'd suggest you go ask your question there, if you haven't already. Derived from [a recent post from there](https://www.antixforum.com/forums/topic/nvidia-drivers-wont-install/):

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/ddm-mx -i nvidia
```

Give it a shot.